# Giving parameters to index.php with RewriteRule

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had a redirector, which gave everything after / in the url to the hidden index.php as a parameter (which then redirects the user with js' window.location later to an another domain, the host does not support external redirections by .htaccess), but I lost the code. Each file (index.php, .htaccess) is in the /storage folder.
The .htaccess was something like this, but I can't figure it out:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /?$1 [R,L]
```

This one is making an infinite loop of redirections.

It worked as entering `http://storage.mysite.com/file.png` would open `http://storage.mysite.com/?file.png`.
I tried to avoid the use of directly calling index.php in the .htaccess, as it redirected with this:

```php
<?php 
   echo "
       <script>
        window.location='http://otherdomain.com/12345678".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."'
       </script> 
   "; // note there's no slash after the number, the REQUEST_URI had it
?>
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is what you need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

In PHP, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will still be the original requested URI `/file.png`.

Getting rid of the R flag will fix the looping. Additionally, there is no need to add the request URI as a GET parameter as explained bellow.
The R flag means that the new address `/?file.png` is sent to the browser and the browser then makes a new request for that URI.
Removing the R flag will mean that Apache serves the new file `index.php` without telling the browser.

This means that although `index.php` is being parsed, the request URI is still `/file.png`.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php` means if the request is for `/index.php`, then it is not rewritten.

I have tested this and it works. If you have any problems please comment.

Comment: Thanks, tried this, now instead of looping it goes straight to 404 and does not do any redirection. I replaced the previous rule from the htaccess file entirely with your version, if that's what you intended. At least giving `storage.mysite.com/?file.png` correctly goes to index.php and it does the redirect.

Comment: So requesting `storage.mysite.com/file.png` gives a 404?
Do you have any other rules in the .htaccess?

Comment: The .htaccess contains this:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`
I've added the 404 line so it doesn't get redirected to the host's own 404 page.

Comment: Sounds like the rewrites aren't being processed. If they were then the 404 request would be rewritten as well and you'd be redirected to `http://otherdomain.com/12345678/404.php`
Try adding `RewriteEngine On` at the top of the .htacces file.
If that doesn't fix it, make a phpinfo() file and look for `mod_rewrite` in the Loaded Modules section.

Comment: I've added `RewriteEngine On`, but it breaks the entire .htaccess file, as it goes to the host's 404 page. If I recall correctly, the original version did not had a `RewriteCond` in it, it was a single line (apart from the `RewriteEngine On`) and it did work, so I don't know what could be the problem now, even though I've been trying to fix it by trial-and-error before posting the question here.

Comment: Peculiar. Sounds like you'll need to just fiddle around and try to diagnose the problem as you have been.

Answer (score 0):

`*` means "0 or more". If you only want to redirect if there is at least one then you should use `+` instead.